# Scipt to add song title and artist to file properties

Tags: windows

As seen in the title, I am looking for a way to use the file (mp3) name (syntax: ARTIST - TITLE) to fill the desired property fields. Is there anyone who has experience with this? And what is the tool to achieve it?

Comment: Avee, welcome!.  Try to add a little more clarity to your question.  You have a filename and you want to use it to change the metadata?  Do you want to do that manually, programmatically?

Comment: Hi, I am doing this manually every few months and was wondering if there were a way to automate it. My idea would be dividing the string with the " - " to differentiate between title and artist and use the two generated strings to fill the property fields.